# Can progress be saved in adventure mode?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is it necessary to complete all five missions in one session? Does the bounty progress always reset when exiting the game?

[image]

*2/5 bounties completed*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bounty progress is not saved when you exit the game. If you want to get the reward for finishing all of the bounties in one act, you need to complete all 5 bounties without exiting the game.